# Run program within C _without_ using a shell

Tags: c, exec, fork

I'm trying to run an application in C, but the only way I could find that is reasonably easy to use works like this:

```
system("command here");
```

It works, of course, but it's really slow (especially when repeating this a lot). I'm just wondering if there is a way of running a program *without* having to interact with a shell, something like [python's subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

I have heard of [`execl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec), and I would use that ([`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork)ing it first, of course), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way that wouldn't require forking first.

**EDIT**: I also want to be able to know the return code of the program

Comment: Python, being built on C, will just be wrapping that functionality. All you need to do is define your own function to fork and exec, then use that wherever you need it.

Comment: @Dave, yes, of course, but how would I know the return code of the program?

Comment: You can `waitpid` (with `WNOHANG` if you want to be asynchronous) which will give you the exit status once it has closed.

Comment: (and, to be clear, the pid is what you get from `fork` if you are in the main program. And you get 0 if you are in the child program)

Comment: You didn't say what OS you have, but you might be able to use `spawn`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawnp

Comment: @Gabe, hmm, interesting... but it really doesn't look too nice (I think `fork`/`execl` would be easier to read)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) nor [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) provides the mechanism you need, then the *easy* way to do it is with [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) (or, perhaps, `execl()`, but the argument list must be fixed at compile time, not variable, to use it).  Really!  It is not hard to do `fork()` and `exec()`, and any alternative will encapsulate that processing.

The Python subprocess module is simply hiding `fork()` and `exec()` for you behind a convenient interface.  That's probably appropriate for a high-level language like Python.  C is a lower-level language and doesn't really need the complexity.

The hard way to do it is with [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).  You have to create arguments to describe all the actions you want done in the child between the `fork()` and the `exec()`, which is far harder to set up than it is to simply do the `fork()`, make the changes, and then use `exec()` after all.  This (`posix_spawn()`) is what you get when you design the code to spawn a child process without visibly using `fork()` and `exec()` and ensure that it can handle almost any reasonable circumstance.

You'll need to consider whether you need to use [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) or [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) or a variant to determine when the child is complete.  You may need to consider whether to handle the SIGCHLD signal (which will notify you when a child dies).

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure you already know, `system` already employs the `fork/exec` strategy. I understand you want to circumvent the shell and are looking for a simple approach, I'm just saying you could just as easily write a function to wrap the `fork/exec` pattern as is done in `system`. Indeed it would probably be most straightforward to just do that. An alternative as Gabe mentioned in the comments is `posix_spawn`.

A faster (but apparently discouraged) alternative is [`vfork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) / `exec`, but this is generally discouraged and is obsolete in the latest POSIX standards.

> 4.3BSD; POSIX.1-2001 (but marked OBSOLETE).  POSIX.1-2008 removes the
>          specification of vfork().

It's meant to be ***immediately*** followed by an `exec` or `_exit`. Otherwise all kinds of weird bugs can arise since the virtual memory pages and page tables aren't duplicated (child uses same data/heap/stack segments). The parent/calling process blocks until the child `exec`s or `_exit`s. Regular `fork`'s modern implementations have copy-on-write semantics which approach the speed of `vfork`, without the potential bugs incurred by `vfork`'s memory sharing semantics.

If you want even *further* control over memory-sharing semantics and process inheritance, and the consequent potential speed-up (and are on Linux), look into [`clone()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (wrapper for system-call `sys_clone()`) which is what some process-creating system calls delegate their work to. Be sure to carefully comb over all of the various flags.

You can use [`waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) to get the exit status of the process.

Comment: `vfork()` is weird; the rules for accurate use are very stringent; it is easy to get it wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. Hopefully I made this clear enough to the OP so that they may more carefully weigh their options.